# How can i block root access to the website and only allow requests with a path

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

I'm using IIS URL rewrite to access a private website however I want to block anyone that visits the root address.

**Block**

- https://example.com
- https://example.com/

**Allow**

- https://example.com/#/test...
- https://example.com/[anything after the domain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block root with a rewrite rule. For example (it will return 403 status code):

```
<rule name="Block root" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Root url is forbidden" />
</rule>
```

This rule will **block**:

- https://example.com
- https://example.com/
- https://example.com/#[something] (because # is [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) which available only on client's browsers and not sending to server)
- https://example.com/?[something] (querystring)

**Allow**:

- https://example.com/[something]